# JPA Criteria Order by enum set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, criteria

### I want to order by set of enum using JPA Criteria

This is my Enum:

```
    public enum UserRole {
    SYS_ADMIN,
    CALIBRATOR_ADMIN,
    PROVIDER_ADMIN,
    }
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

@Embedded
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "organizationId")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Organization organization;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "value", length = 30)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
```

And how I try to make search query:

```
public static CriteriaQuery<User> buildSearchQuery(String userName, String role, String firstName, String lastName, EntityManager em, String fieldToSort) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);

        Predicate predicate = ProviderEmployeeQuary.buildPredicate(root, cb, userName,role, firstName, lastName);

if (fieldToSort.length() > 0) {
            if (fieldToSort.substring(0, 1).equals("-")) {
                if (fieldToSort.substring(1, fieldToSort.length()).equals("userRoles")) {   
                    criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.desc(root.<Set<UserRole>>get(fieldToSort.substring(1, fieldToSort.length()))));
                } else {
                    criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(fieldToSort.substring(1, fieldToSort.length()))));
                }
            } else {
                if (fieldToSort.equals("userRoles")) {

                    criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.asc(root.<Set<UserRole>>get(fieldToSort)));

                } else {
                    criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(fieldToSort)));
                }
            }
        }
        criteriaQuery.select(root).distinct(true);
        criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
        return criteriaQuery;
    }
```

Error of executing this code is:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'asc limit 5' at
>   line 1

Generated JPQL query:

> select distinct generatedAlias0 from User as generatedAlias0 inner
>   join generatedAlias0.organization as generatedAlias1 where (
>   generatedAlias1.id=11L ) and ( 1=1 ) order by
>   generatedAlias0.userRoles desc

Comment: You are joining table on enum field? Mind blown.

Comment: @Atais, this code was written before me. My task only to make ordering

Comment: In previous version of this entity was many-to-many relation with enum field, and, as I understand, it was made for optimization, but I'm not sure

Comment: Is the enum an entity as well? Anyway for the soring something like `cb.asc(root.get(fieldToSort)` should do. If it does not work, post the sql which is generated by CriteriaBuilder

Comment: It is not entity. I added generated query